# How to limit pages to be printed on java printing using linux/CUPS with IPP?

Tags: java, linux, cups, intel-ipp

I'm struggling to limit the pages to be printed.

I'm using: Java17, Ubuntu 20.04

Using this example, selecting a PDF and limiting the page with `PageRanges` attribute will just not work.

IPP specification has the `page-ranges` attribute.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, PrintException {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(inputStream, flavor, null);
            PrintService ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
            DocPrintJob printJob = ps.createPrintJob();

            PrintRequestAttributeSet attributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            attributeSet.add(new PageRanges(1));
            printJob.print(doc, attributeSet);
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
    System.out.println("---> %s".formatted(printService.getName()));

    List.of(PageRanges.class, Copies.class, PrintQuality.class, Sides.class)
            .forEach(i -> System.out.println("%s -> %s".formatted(
                    i.getName(),
                    printService.isAttributeCategorySupported(i))));
}
```

Outputs:

```
---> PDF
javax.print.attribute.standard.PageRanges -> true
javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies -> true
javax.print.attribute.standard.PrintQuality -> false
javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides -> true
---> SP-3710SF
javax.print.attribute.standard.PageRanges -> true
javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies -> true
javax.print.attribute.standard.PrintQuality -> false
javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides -> true
```

Edit 2:

There's a statement on [PageRanges](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/print/attribute/standard/PageRanges.html) about IPP (But I did not really know what it means):

IPP Compatibility: The PageRanges attribute's canonical array form gives the lower and upper bound for each range of pages to be included in and IPP "page-ranges" attribute. See class SetOfIntegerSyntax for an explanation of canonical array form. The category name returned by getName() gives the IPP attribute name.

Comment: What about `attributeSet.add(new PageRanges(1, 2));`?

Comment: What does `System.out.println(ps.isAttributeCategorySupported(PageRanges.class));` display?

Comment: @g00se Yes, I've tried this one an `new PageRanges(new int[][]{{1}})`

Comment: Different. What's the answer to @VGR's question?

Comment: @VGR I thought It would return false, but it returns true. I've updated the question.